# PhpStorm CodeIgniter custom objects autocomplete

Tags: php, codeigniter, autocomplete, phpstorm

I am struggling with custom objects autocomplete within Controllers/Views.

Sample code

```
$this->category      = $this->site_model->get_category($this->uri->uri_string());
    $this->languages     = $this->site_model->get_lang();
    $this->slider        = $this->site_model->get_slider();
    $this->static_texts  = $this->site_model->get_texts();
    $this->ads           = $this->site_model->get_ads();
    $this->currencies    = $this->site_model->get_currencies();
    $this->brands        = $this->site_model->get_brands(array('brand_visible'=>1));
    $this->goals         = $this->site_model->get_goal();
    $this->promo         = $this->site_model->get_promo();
```

These variables are running DB queries and generating arrays of objects. I want to generate PHP doc so PhpStorm can provide autocomplete.

For example:

`$this->slider` contains array:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#81 (3) {
    ["slide_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["slide_src"]=>
    string(13) "iamge.jpg"
    ["slide_href"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#80 (3) {
    ["slide_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["slide_src"]=>
    string(10) "image2.jpg"
    ["slide_href"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#79 (3) {
    ["slide_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["slide_src"]=>
    string(14) "image3.jpg"
    ["slide_href"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#78 (3) {
    ["slide_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["slide_src"]=>
    string(13) "img.jpg"
    ["slide_href"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Should I declare PHPDoc in the controller? In the views? Please help.

So far I made this in views so I don't get undefined variable. But I don't know what should I do with the arrays / objects.

```
<?php
/**
 * @see Site::index()
 * @var array $products
 */
?>
```

Comment: Well .. simply speaking `$this->slider` is an array of `stdClass` instances. I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter (I do not know how `slider` is actually declared in your class -- is that a real field (you have something like `public $slider;` or is it dynamically created field; how it is then accessed in the view file (`$this->slider` .. or just `$slider`?)

Comment: Hi, yes it is declared var $slider.  in view it is accessed by $this->slider

Comment: But generally speaking `$this->slider` can be type hinted with `/** @var stdClass[] */` if placed just above `public $slider;` sort of line (it's in Controller and not View). Now .. this will still not add any code completion help as `slide_id` and other fields are still unknown to IDE -- all what it does it stops from complaining on unknown fields (as `stdClass` is processed in "relaxed" mode .. so you will see no extra warnings for `$this->slider[0]->slide_id` usage).

Comment: Neither PHPDoc or PhpStorm allows you to specify different sets of fields to the same class (I mean -- you cannot make so that in one place `stdClass` instance will have these fields in autocompletion and in another place -- different set). The workaround here is to use "fake" classes (used by IDE only .. or by your code as well if you want to bother with this that much -- but in this case it will be real classes).

Comment: I have phpstorm.php file in root directory where I have some CI_Controller class declared with comments above so I get default libraries autocomplete. How can I declare Slider class there with attributes?

Comment: The idea is -- declare `$this->slider` as array of `Slider` instances (e.g. `/** @var Slider[] */` if placed above `public $slider;` declaration. Now you need to declare this "fake" `Slider` class somewhere -- it can be any file in your project (as it will be used by IDE only) -- you just declare it there as ordinary PHP class with all the fields/methods made public -- that's it.

Comment: well but anyway I would have to declare it in the view I think. I will just stick with my own doc to look up variables cos I dont think I can make this run as I want

Comment: Sure. Just keep in mind that you cannot typehint 2nd level entity with PHPDoc (you cannot use `/** @var Slider[] $this->slider */`) -- only 1st level (for that you will have to introduce intermediate variable, e.g. `$slider = $this->slider;` which you now can typehint `/** @var Slider[] $slider */`)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of some of mine for you

```
/**
 * Create signing signature
 * @param   array   $params  Signature components
 * @param   string  $secret  Token secret (if required)
 * @param   string  $url     url for request method
 * @return  string           oAuth signature ready for use
 * @throws  Exception
 */
protected function makeSignature($url, $params, $secret = null)
{
```

this could also be helpful for you: https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/basic-syntax.html

Comment: well those are kind of propertie cos I am using them accross whole application and I need to define params of those properties

Comment: Phpstorm has issues with following codeigniters structure, the phpdocs will work pretty much in the area you have set them but not throughout the chain

Comment: well I can put the phpdoc in each view but I would need more complex doc style for the array. How could I define that $slider is array of object and then define attributes of the object?

Comment: Phpdoc is not designed to go down to that level, it explains the top level, doesn't define structure inside of that structure

Comment: Well .. technically it can describe array structure .. but for `@param` tags only (as I understand) -- see https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#713-param . I'm not sure if it will work in other tags like `@var` for example). In any case: PhpStorm does not support it yet -- you need 3rd party plugin for that (it exists -- just install it).